# PHP date() look causing to read wrong timezone

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have a function which updates a `datetime` in a MySQL db in a recursive manner.

```
if($_POST['action'] == 'check orders in') {
     //check the value for match
     if($_POST['checkin_orders'] && is_array($_POST['checkin_orders'])) {
         foreach($_POST['checkin_orders'] as $oid){
             $db->update_order($oid, array('orderfulfilled_ts'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
             send_order_sent_email($oid);
         }
     }
     jsoo_redirect("/admin/orb-check-in");
}
```

With my php.ini set to the correct timezone, this works well, however, when this is run with multiple values being sent through (multiple orders are being checked in), the first order get the correct timezone while the second order gets the server timezone.

Is there a better way I should be approaching this situation?

P.S. I have tried date_defult_timezone_set in the `foreach` loop with no solution.

in my db.php file, here are the two functions that are connected to updating order:

update_order

```
 1522     function update_order($id, $args) {
 1523         return $this->update_row(REGION_PREFIX."Order", $id, $args);
 1524     }
```

update_row

```
  901     function update_row($table, $id, $values) {
  902         $this->assert_connected();
  903         $this->assert_table_exists($table);
  904         if (!isset($id)) die ("update_row expects \$id to be set");
  905         if (!is_array($values)) die ("update_row expects \$values to be an associative array");
  906         if (count($values)==0) return STATUS_NOCHANGE;
  907 
  908         $sql = "UPDATE `$table` SET ";
  909 
  910         $i=0;
  911         foreach($this->table_fields[$table] as $field=>$type) {
  912             if (isset($values[$field]) && $this->is_db_field($table,$field)){
  913                 if ($i!=0) $sql .= ",";
  914                 $sql .= "`$field` = '". $this->sanitize_field($table, $field, $values[$field]) ."'";
  915                 $i++;
  916             }
  917         }
  918 
  919         $sql .= " WHERE `id` = $id;";
  920 //      echo $sql;
  921         if ($this->conn->query($sql)) return $id;
  922         else return STATUS_FAILURE;
  923     }
```

edit: Included two connecting functions.

Comment: I see nothing in this code that would cause your issue. You'd better post some more. Maybe your update_order method.

Comment: Add `echo date_default_timezone_get();` inside your foreach loop to see the timezone for each loop and see if it's actually different.

Comment: @Ali the echo output: America/New_YorkEtc/UTC

Comment: @rjdown updated question with two connecting functions.